# Is there a regular expression to remove a trailing slash in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to remove a trailing slash from a string. For example if i have a string called 
$test = "test/". How would I remove the slash at the end?

Comment: Did you read the documentation *at all*? e.g. http://perldoc.perl.org/perreftut.html?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are sure that there is one / at the end all the time you can use the chop function:

```
$test = "test/";
$test = chop($test);
```

If you are not sure you can do:

```
$test = "test/";
$test = $1 if($test=~/(.*)\/$/);
```

Comment: Useless use of capturing group, and if the string contains new lines it will break too.

Comment: Wow, both of these examples are wrong. You have to test to see that the last character is a / if you use chop, and the $ anchor allows a newline after the last character. Instead of a match, just use a substitution: `s|/\z||;`

Answer (score 12):

With a regular expression do: `$test =~ s/\/$//`

Alternatively, if you're sure the last character is going to be a slash, you can use the [chop](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chop.html) function: `chop $test`

Comment: Use the \z anchor to get the absolute end of string.

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but it seems that this regex does work for all directories, *except* when using 'root directory'* --> / <--. It will simply remove the root path, which is not so good in some cases, because it'll starts with a trailing slash (paradoxon?). ;-)

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `s///` substitution operator:

```
$test =~ s{/\z}{};
```

Comment: Use the \z anchor to get the absolute end of string.

Answer (score 8):

Personally I would rephrase this to avoid the mixture of "\" and "/"

```
$test =~ s|/$||
```

If you use "|" you don't need to quote the "/"

Comment: Use the \z anchor to get the absolute end of string.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will take care of trailing slashes, except for the root directory:

```html
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $test = './';
$test =~ s{(.+)/\z}{\1};
print $test."\n";
```

Here is how it works:

The first part of the regular expression - **s{(.+)/\z}** - defines a group in the brackets **()**. This is referenced by the **\1** in the second part of the regular expression - **{\1}**. Within this group, I defined one or more characters - **.+** - followed immediately by a forward slash, followed by the absolute end of the string - **\z**.

The regular expression saves everything within the brackets, to be later used as **\1** in the replacement specification (the second part, basically.)

This works very similar to a typical sed strategy, viz:

```html
echo "./" | sed -e 's:\(..*\)/$:\1:'
```

I hope this is of help to you.

Comment: Nice to see one that addresses the real-world problem of the root directory.
Two additional ideas:
1) I believe the recommended way of substituting captures in the replacement is with "$" rather than "\", though both work.
2) It may be more efficient to just capture the character just before the trailing /, instead of potentially very very many characters.

Incorporating both of those changes, I'd make it:
`s{(.)/\z}{$1}`